# How to parse the character in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, encode

I'm using PHP and MySQL `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to import about 200,000 lines of data from an external file. However, I get a character issue somewhere with the text `KOA`.

On Windows server, I got `KO` when reading this field from database: [image]

On Linux server, I got some unreadable code: [image]

Therefore, I tried to encode the character `O` in `KOA` and found it be `\x4F\xC2\x9D` instead of `\x4F`...

I'm wondering if there is anyway to parse the whole file and output the correct characters without manually change the content in the file?

Possibly some functions in PHP or using NPM?

Comment: Shall we assume that you don't have any clue about the encoding that's supposedly used by any of the involved actors (PHP, MySQL and CSV)? Do you at least know the language spoken by the company that provides the data?

Answer (score 0):

First open data file in notepad++ 
then click on **Encoding** > **convert to UTF-8** and save it.

Now upload data on mysql database server.

Comment: If you don't know the source encoding, isn't this a lottery?